# Matlab For loop assign Vector values and Plot Them

Tags: matlab

I try to loop from 0 to 10 and try to assign the Rb value to the Rb index of RbArray:

```
for Rb=0:10
  RbArray(Rb) = Rb;
end

plot(Rb)
```

However, I get the error:

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
>
> Error in test (line 2)
>       RbArray(Rb) = Rb;

Comment: Your first loop iteration attempts to index `RbArray` with `0`. Is `0` a real positive integer?

Comment: I forgot indices cannot start at 0 in matlab. Thanks!